# Google analytics tracking snippet and analytics.js modification

Tags: google-analytics

Is modification of tracking script and/or analytics.js allowed under the Google Analytics [terms of service](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html)?

Does analytics.js fall under the GTAC category or is it just the tracking snippet.

> "GATC" means the Google Analytics Tracking Code, which is installed on a Property for the purpose of collecting Customer Data, together with any fixes, updates and upgrades provided to You.

And what does "solely as necessary" signify?

> You a limited, revocable, non-exclusive, non-sublicensable license to install, copy and use the GATC solely as necessary for You to use the Service on Your Properties or Third Party's Properties

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while interesting, it is a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, any other stackexchange site that'd be suitable for this question?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com has a few questions on software licences, and since this is a legal question it might be appropriate (at least this meta question suggests licensing questions are on topic there: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/software-licensing-questions-from-stackoverflow).